# Why builtin function type() gives different output when class is a subclass of an object class?

Tags: python

Why `type(Foo)` is different from `type(Bar)` and `type(foo)` is different from `type(bar)`?

```
>>> class Foo: pass   
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> class Bar(object): pass 
...
>>> bar = Bar()
>>>
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(foo)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(Bar)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(bar)
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```